# Unable to Restore a Database to a previous point in time from a Full Backup Set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

[image]

I have a full backup set (SQL server) and I am trying to restore the Database to a previous date and time. Every time I restore it (To another database) selecting a previous date that I want from the backup set, its RESTORES the latest version of the data. I can still query for data after the point in time.
All I want to for the backup to stop at the point in time indicated (see image)

Is there something that i am missing?

DB: SQL server 2000

Tool used: Enterprise manager

Comment: I doubt anyone here remembers how Enterprise Manager works, so a screenshot is not really useful.  Minimally you would need to provide the TSQL backup command used, any message output the RESTORE produced and any SQL Log entries written.

Comment: Related to David's comment: you might have better luck with using SSMS 2008, which still supported SQL Server 2000, but is a new enough tool that folks here will be able to help you get to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what backups you have. If you only have a full backup, then there's no point-i-time restore. It can only be restored to the "snapshot in time" it reflects (towards the end of the backup period).

If you *do* have also transaction log backups, then I agree that you should test SSMS and see what RESTORE commands it generates (you have a script button to see the TSQL) and then take it from there.